# Code Listing in Atollic True Studio style

Tags: code

has someone got latex listing settings, that the code appears as follows?

[image: desired style]

thanks in advance!

Comment: Fairly standard C code.  Pretty much any of the listing packages should be able to handle it.

Comment: Hi, there is no problem with handling the code! I just cant find the color and font settings that makes it look quite similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this? You can modify the colors according to your taste. For more details of the specific keywords, refer to the [listings manual](https://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf).

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    %basewidth={0.5em,0.5em},
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=t,
    frame=single,
    framerule=1pt,
    columns=flexible,                    
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=4,
    morekeywords={[2]{uint32_t}},
    keywordstyle={[2]\color{magenta}},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
static void func(void)
{
    if(condition1) {
        printf("Statement 1");
    } else {
        uint32_t var = value;
        printf("Statement 2");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

### Edit

To add the line numbers, use these settings.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}
{
    language=C++,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\color{green},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},
    stringstyle=\color{red},
    %basewidth={0.5em,0.5em},
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    breaklines=true,
    captionpos=t,
    frame=single,
    framerule=1pt,
    columns=flexible,
    keepspaces=true,
    showspaces=false,
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,
    tabsize=4,
    morekeywords={[2]{uint32_t}},
    keywordstyle={[2]\color{magenta}},
    numberstyle=\sffamily\footnotesize\color{gray},
    numbers=left,
    numbersep=10pt,
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[style=mystyle]
static void func(void)
{
    if(condition1) {
        printf("Statement 1");
    } else {
        uint32_t var = value;
        printf("Statement 2");
    }
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thats looking good, thank you!
Is there a way to insert the line numbers on the left side of the code as well?

Comment: @KEKO, edited my answer.

Comment: awesome, thank you!

Comment: Please accept the answer to let others also know that your question has been addressed.